# Assistance to scrape an html document in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I need help to understand how to import in R the table shown in the following html document.

https://www.agerborsamerci.it/listino/listino.html

I am new to the world of web scraping, so I would also ask if you could briefly explain how you did this.

Thank you very much for your help and time

Comment: Take a look to https://www.storybench.org/scraping-html-tables-and-downloading-files-with-r/

Answer (score 1):

The firsts steps would be something like this

```
library( rvest )

url    <- "https://www.agerborsamerci.it/listino/web.htm"
file   <- read_html( url )
tables <- html_nodes( file, "table" )
table1 <- html_table( tables[1], fill = TRUE )
```

But after that, you will have to do some (read: probably a lot of) data wrangling to get nice, clean, tidy data.